# get access denied on samba AD share

Tags: centos, samba, samba4

I can not access my samba shares after upgrade my centos to 7.4,samba version was upgraded to 4.6.2
I joined centos to windows domain by realm command,domain user(format as username@doaminname) could login to centos
could get kerberos ticket by kinit with domain user

execute net view command at domain windows server get access denied

```
C:\>net view \\ark-centos-smb4.qa.arkivio.com
System error 5 has occurred.

Access is denied.


C:\>net view \\192.168.32.26
System error 5 has occurred.

Access is denied.
```

collected following log while get access denied error with samba server ip, I complains can not find the user,and run `getent passwd domainuser@domainname` could finish successfully:

```
[2017/09/21 00:36:03.319546,  3]
../source3/smbd/oplock.c:1322(init_oplocks)   init_oplocks:
initializing messages. [2017/09/21 00:36:03.319707,  3]
../source3/smbd/process.c:1957(process_smb)   Transaction 0 of length
159 (0 toread) [2017/09/21 00:36:03.319744,  3]
../source3/smbd/process.c:1538(switch_message)   switch message
SMBnegprot (pid 23703) conn 0x0 [2017/09/21 00:36:03.319767,  4]
../source3/smbd/sec_ctx.c:321(set_sec_ctx_internal)   setting sec ctx
(0, 0) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 0 [2017/09/21 00:36:03.320414,  3]
../source3/smbd/negprot.c:603(reply_negprot)   Requested protocol [PC
NETWORK PROGRAM 1.0] [2017/09/21 00:36:03.320441,  3]
../source3/smbd/negprot.c:603(reply_negprot)   Requested protocol
[LANMAN1.0] [2017/09/21 00:36:03.320454,  3]
../source3/smbd/negprot.c:603(reply_negprot)   Requested protocol
[Windows for Workgroups 3.1a] [2017/09/21 00:36:03.320466,  3]
../source3/smbd/negprot.c:603(reply_negprot)   Requested protocol
[LM1.2X002] [2017/09/21 00:36:03.320482,  3]
../source3/smbd/negprot.c:603(reply_negprot)   Requested protocol
[LANMAN2.1] [2017/09/21 00:36:03.320497,  3]
../source3/smbd/negprot.c:603(reply_negprot)   Requested protocol [NT
LM 0.12] [2017/09/21 00:36:03.320509,  3]
../source3/smbd/negprot.c:603(reply_negprot)   Requested protocol [SMB
2.002] [2017/09/21 00:36:03.320538,  3] ../source3/smbd/negprot.c:603(reply_negprot)   Requested protocol [SMB
2.???] [2017/09/21 00:36:03.320638,  4] ../source3/smbd/sec_ctx.c:321(set_sec_ctx_internal)   setting sec ctx
(0, 0) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 0 [2017/09/21 00:36:03.320722,  3]
../source3/smbd/smb2_negprot.c:290(smbd_smb2_request_process_negprot)
Selected protocol SMB2_FF [2017/09/21 00:36:03.321314,  2]
../source3/librpc/crypto/gse_krb5.c:229(fill_mem_keytab_from_secrets)
../source3/librpc/crypto/gse_krb5.c:229: failed to fetch machine
password [2017/09/21 00:36:03.321344,  3]
../source3/librpc/crypto/gse_krb5.c:587(gse_krb5_get_server_keytab)
../source3/librpc/crypto/gse_krb5.c:587: Warning! Unable to set mem
keytab from secrets! [2017/09/21 00:36:03.322377,  3]
../source3/smbd/negprot.c:730(reply_negprot)   Selected protocol SMB
2.??? [2017/09/21 00:36:03.323207,  4] ../source3/smbd/sec_ctx.c:321(set_sec_ctx_internal)   setting sec ctx
(0, 0) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 0 [2017/09/21 00:36:03.323262,  4]
../source3/smbd/sec_ctx.c:217(push_sec_ctx)   push_sec_ctx(0, 0) :
sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 1 [2017/09/21 00:36:03.323300,  4]
../source3/smbd/uid.c:491(push_conn_ctx)   push_conn_ctx(0) :
conn_ctx_stack_ndx = 0 [2017/09/21 00:36:03.323326,  4]
../source3/smbd/sec_ctx.c:321(set_sec_ctx_internal)   setting sec ctx
(0, 0) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 1 [2017/09/21 00:36:03.325145,  4]
../source3/smbd/sec_ctx.c:439(pop_sec_ctx)   pop_sec_ctx (0, 0) -
sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 0 [2017/09/21 00:36:03.325187,  3]
../source3/smbd/smb2_negprot.c:290(smbd_smb2_request_process_negprot)
Selected protocol SMB2_10 [2017/09/21 00:36:03.325448,  2]
../source3/librpc/crypto/gse_krb5.c:229(fill_mem_keytab_from_secrets)
../source3/librpc/crypto/gse_krb5.c:229: failed to fetch machine
password [2017/09/21 00:36:03.325466,  3]
../source3/librpc/crypto/gse_krb5.c:587(gse_krb5_get_server_keytab)
../source3/librpc/crypto/gse_krb5.c:587: Warning! Unable to set mem
keytab from secrets! [2017/09/21 00:36:03.327171,  4]
../source3/smbd/sec_ctx.c:321(set_sec_ctx_internal)   setting sec ctx
(0, 0) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 0 [2017/09/21 00:36:03.327477,  4]
../source3/smbd/sec_ctx.c:217(push_sec_ctx)   push_sec_ctx(0, 0) :
sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 1 [2017/09/21 00:36:03.327498,  4]
../source3/smbd/uid.c:491(push_conn_ctx)   push_conn_ctx(0) :
conn_ctx_stack_ndx = 0 [2017/09/21 00:36:03.327509,  4]
../source3/smbd/sec_ctx.c:321(set_sec_ctx_internal)   setting sec ctx
(0, 0) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 1 [2017/09/21 00:36:03.327562,  4]
../source3/smbd/sec_ctx.c:439(pop_sec_ctx)   pop_sec_ctx (0, 0) -
sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 0 [2017/09/21 00:36:03.327754,  3]
../auth/ntlmssp/ntlmssp_util.c:69(debug_ntlmssp_flags)   Got NTLMSSP
neg_flags=0xe2088297
    NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_UNICODE
    NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_OEM
    NTLMSSP_REQUEST_TARGET
    NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_SIGN
    NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_LM_KEY
    NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_NTLM
    NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_ALWAYS_SIGN
    NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_EXTENDED_SESSIONSECURITY
    NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_VERSION
    NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_128
    NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_KEY_EXCH
    NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_56 [2017/09/21 00:36:03.327897,  4] ../source3/smbd/sec_ctx.c:217(push_sec_ctx)   push_sec_ctx(0, 0) :
sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 1 [2017/09/21 00:36:03.327919,  4]
../source3/smbd/uid.c:491(push_conn_ctx)   push_conn_ctx(0) :
conn_ctx_stack_ndx = 0 [2017/09/21 00:36:03.327930,  4]
../source3/smbd/sec_ctx.c:321(set_sec_ctx_internal)   setting sec ctx
(0, 0) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 1 [2017/09/21 00:36:03.327951,  4]
../source3/smbd/sec_ctx.c:439(pop_sec_ctx)   pop_sec_ctx (0, 0) -
sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 0 [2017/09/21 00:36:03.328313,  4]
../source3/smbd/sec_ctx.c:321(set_sec_ctx_internal)   setting sec ctx
(0, 0) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 0 [2017/09/21 00:36:03.328360,  4]
../source3/smbd/sec_ctx.c:217(push_sec_ctx)   push_sec_ctx(0, 0) :
sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 1 [2017/09/21 00:36:03.328376,  4]
../source3/smbd/uid.c:491(push_conn_ctx)   push_conn_ctx(0) :
conn_ctx_stack_ndx = 0 [2017/09/21 00:36:03.328387,  4]
../source3/smbd/sec_ctx.c:321(set_sec_ctx_internal)   setting sec ctx
(0, 0) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 1 [2017/09/21 00:36:03.328403,  4]
../source3/smbd/sec_ctx.c:439(pop_sec_ctx)   pop_sec_ctx (0, 0) -
sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 0 [2017/09/21 00:36:03.328478,  3]
../auth/ntlmssp/ntlmssp_server.c:452(ntlmssp_server_preauth)   Got
user=[arkadmin] domain=[QA] workstation=[NWT-VM-ARK8118] len1=24
len2=350 [2017/09/21 00:36:03.328573,  3]
../source3/param/loadparm.c:3823(lp_load_ex)   lp_load_ex: refreshing
parameters [2017/09/21 00:36:03.328664,  3]
../source3/param/loadparm.c:542(init_globals)   Initialising global
parameters [2017/09/21 00:36:03.328773,  3]
../source3/param/loadparm.c:2752(lp_do_section)   Processing section
"[global]"   doing parameter netbios name = ARK-CENTOS-SMB4   doing
parameter security = ADS   doing parameter workgroup = QA.ARKIVIO.COM
doing parameter kerberos method = secrets and keytab   doing parameter
realm = QA.ARKIVIO.COM   doing parameter log file =
/var/log/samba/%m.log   doing parameter log level = 4   doing
parameter local master = no   doing parameter domain master = no
doing parameter server string = Samba Server Version %v   doing
parameter max log size = 5000   doing parameter load printers = No
doing parameter wins support = no   doing parameter wins proxy = no
doing parameter dns proxy = yes   doing parameter name resolve order =
host lmhosts wins bcast [2017/09/21 00:36:03.328953,  2]
../source3/param/loadparm.c:2769(lp_do_section)   Processing section
"[arkc1]"   doing parameter comment = centos samba4 share1   doing
parameter path = /rocket/cifs/cifs1   doing parameter writable = yes
doing parameter guest ok = yes   doing parameter valid users =
administrator@qa.arkivio.com,auto-stor@qa.arkivio.com,arkadmin@qa.arkivio.com,@"Domain
Admins@qa.arkivio.com",@"AutostorAdmins@qa.arkivio.com","QA.ARKIVIO.COM\AutostorAdmins",arkadmin@QA.ARKIVIO.COM
doing parameter admin users =
administrator@qa.arkivio.com,auto-stor@qa.arkivio.com,arkadmin@qa.arkivio.com,@"Domain
Admins@qa.arkivio.com",@"AutostorAdmins@qa.arkivio.com",arkadmin@QA.ARKIVIO.COM,QA\arkadmin,QA.ARKIVIO.COM\arkadmin
[2017/09/21 00:36:03.329055,  2]
../source3/param/loadparm.c:2769(lp_do_section)   Processing section
"[arkc2]"   doing parameter comment = centos samba4 share2   doing
parameter path = /rocket/cifs/cifs2   doing parameter writable = yes
doing parameter admin users =
administrator@qa.arkivio.com,auto-stor@qa.arkivio.com,arkadmin@qa.arkivio.com,@"Domain
Admins@qa.arkivio.com",@"AutostorAdmins@qa.arkivio.com",arkadmin@QA.ARKIVIO.COM,QA\arkadmin,QA.ARKIVIO.COM\arkadmin
doing parameter valid users =
administrator@qa.arkivio.com,auto-stor@qa.arkivio.com,arkadmin@qa.arkivio.com,@"Domain
Admins@qa.arkivio.com",@"AutostorAdmins@qa.arkivio.com","QA.ARKIVIO.COM\AutostorAdmins",arkadmin@QA.ARKIVIO.COM,QA\arkadmin,QA.ARKIVIO.COM\arkadmin
[2017/09/21 00:36:03.329149,  4]
../source3/param/loadparm.c:3864(lp_load_ex)   pm_process() returned
Yes [2017/09/21 00:36:03.329186,  3]
../source3/param/loadparm.c:1592(lp_add_ipc)   adding IPC service
[2017/09/21 00:36:03.329981,  4]
../source3/libsmb/namequery_dc.c:77(ads_dc_name)   ads_dc_name:
domain=QA.ARKIVIO.COM [2017/09/21 00:36:03.331294,  3]
../source3/libsmb/namequery.c:3160(get_dc_list)   get_dc_list:
preferred server list: ", *" [2017/09/21 00:36:03.332043,  4]
../lib/addns/dnsquery.c:435(ads_dns_lookup_srv)   ads_dns_lookup_srv:
2 records returned in the answer section. [2017/09/21 00:36:03.333572,
4] ../source3/libsmb/namequery.c:3305(get_dc_list)   get_dc_list:
returning 3 ip addresses in an ordered list [2017/09/21
00:36:03.333594,  4] ../source3/libsmb/namequery.c:3306(get_dc_list)
get_dc_list: 192.168.32.231:389 192.168.32.230:389
2001:21:21:32:743e:17d2:61a4:fdb8:389 [2017/09/21 00:36:03.334552,  3]
../source3/libads/ldap.c:618(ads_connect)   Successfully contacted
LDAP server 192.168.32.231 [2017/09/21 00:36:03.334622,  3]
../source3/libsmb/namequery.c:3160(get_dc_list)   get_dc_list:
preferred server list: ", *" [2017/09/21 00:36:03.334961,  4]
../lib/addns/dnsquery.c:435(ads_dns_lookup_srv)   ads_dns_lookup_srv:
2 records returned in the answer section. [2017/09/21 00:36:03.335007,
4] ../source3/libsmb/namequery.c:3305(get_dc_list)   get_dc_list:
returning 3 ip addresses in an ordered list [2017/09/21
00:36:03.335023,  4] ../source3/libsmb/namequery.c:3306(get_dc_list)
get_dc_list: 192.168.32.230:88 192.168.32.231:88
2001:21:21:32:743e:17d2:61a4:fdb8:88 [2017/09/21 00:36:03.335042,  3]
../source3/libsmb/namequery.c:3160(get_dc_list)   get_dc_list:
preferred server list: ", *" [2017/09/21 00:36:03.335419,  4]
../lib/addns/dnsquery.c:435(ads_dns_lookup_srv)   ads_dns_lookup_srv:
2 records returned in the answer section. [2017/09/21 00:36:03.335463,
4] ../source3/libsmb/namequery.c:3305(get_dc_list)   get_dc_list:
returning 3 ip addresses in an ordered list [2017/09/21
00:36:03.335478,  4] ../source3/libsmb/namequery.c:3306(get_dc_list)
get_dc_list: 192.168.32.230:88 192.168.32.231:88
2001:21:21:32:743e:17d2:61a4:fdb8:88 [2017/09/21 00:36:03.336391,  4]
../source3/libsmb/namequery_dc.c:151(ads_dc_name)   ads_dc_name: using
server='ARK-QA-DC2.QA.ARKIVIO.COM' IP=192.168.32.231 [2017/09/21
00:36:03.336496,  3]
../source3/lib/util_sock.c:515(open_socket_out_send)   Connecting to
192.168.32.231 at port 445 [2017/09/21 00:36:03.337733,  3] ../source3/libsmb/cliconnect.c:271(cli_session_creds_prepare_krb5)
got OID=1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.2.30   got OID=1.2.840.48018.1.2.2
[2017/09/21 00:36:03.338945,  3]
../auth/ntlmssp/ntlmssp_client.c:270(ntlmssp_client_challenge)   Got
challenge flags: [2017/09/21 00:36:03.338973,  3]
../auth/ntlmssp/ntlmssp_util.c:69(debug_ntlmssp_flags)   Got NTLMSSP
neg_flags=0x62898215
    NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_UNICODE
    NTLMSSP_REQUEST_TARGET
    NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_SIGN
    NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_NTLM
    NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_ALWAYS_SIGN
    NTLMSSP_TARGET_TYPE_DOMAIN
    NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_EXTENDED_SESSIONSECURITY
    NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_TARGET_INFO
    NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_VERSION
    NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_128
    NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_KEY_EXCH [2017/09/21 00:36:03.339060,  3] ../auth/ntlmssp/ntlmssp_client.c:726(ntlmssp_client_challenge)
NTLMSSP: Set final flags: [2017/09/21 00:36:03.339076,  3]
../auth/ntlmssp/ntlmssp_util.c:69(debug_ntlmssp_flags)   Got NTLMSSP
neg_flags=0x62008a15
    NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_UNICODE
    NTLMSSP_REQUEST_TARGET
    NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_SIGN
    NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_NTLM
    NTLMSSP_ANONYMOUS
    NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_ALWAYS_SIGN
    NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_VERSION
    NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_128
    NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_KEY_EXCH [2017/09/21 00:36:03.339112,  3] ../auth/ntlmssp/ntlmssp_sign.c:509(ntlmssp_sign_reset)   NTLMSSP
Sign/Seal - Initialising with flags: [2017/09/21 00:36:03.339123,  3]
../auth/ntlmssp/ntlmssp_util.c:69(debug_ntlmssp_flags)   Got NTLMSSP
neg_flags=0x62008a15
    NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_UNICODE
    NTLMSSP_REQUEST_TARGET
    NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_SIGN
    NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_NTLM
    NTLMSSP_ANONYMOUS
    NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_ALWAYS_SIGN
    NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_VERSION
    NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_128
    NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_KEY_EXCH [2017/09/21 00:36:03.339972,  3] ../auth/ntlmssp/ntlmssp_sign.c:509(ntlmssp_sign_reset)   NTLMSSP
Sign/Seal - Initialising with flags: [2017/09/21 00:36:03.340000,  3]
../auth/ntlmssp/ntlmssp_util.c:69(debug_ntlmssp_flags)   Got NTLMSSP
neg_flags=0x62008a15
    NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_UNICODE
    NTLMSSP_REQUEST_TARGET
    NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_SIGN
    NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_NTLM
    NTLMSSP_ANONYMOUS
    NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_ALWAYS_SIGN
    NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_VERSION
    NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_128
    NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_KEY_EXCH [2017/09/21 00:36:03.344582,  3] ../source3/auth/auth.c:178(auth_check_ntlm_password)
check_ntlm_password:  Checking password for unmapped user
[QA]\[arkadmin]@[NWT-VM-ARK8118] with the new password interface
[2017/09/21 00:36:03.344615,  3]
../source3/auth/auth.c:181(auth_check_ntlm_password)
check_ntlm_password:  mapped user is:
[ARK-CENTOS-SMB4]\[arkadmin]@[NWT-VM-ARK8118] [2017/09/21
00:36:03.344650,  4] ../source3/smbd/sec_ctx.c:217(push_sec_ctx)
push_sec_ctx(0, 0) : sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 1 [2017/09/21
00:36:03.344698,  4] ../source3/smbd/uid.c:491(push_conn_ctx)
push_conn_ctx(0) : conn_ctx_stack_ndx = 0 [2017/09/21 00:36:03.344714,
4] ../source3/smbd/sec_ctx.c:321(set_sec_ctx_internal)   setting sec
ctx (0, 0) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 1 [2017/09/21 00:36:03.344768,  4]
../source3/smbd/sec_ctx.c:439(pop_sec_ctx)   pop_sec_ctx (0, 0) -
sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 0 [2017/09/21 00:36:03.344785,  3]
../source3/auth/check_samsec.c:399(check_sam_security)
check_sam_security: Couldn't find user 'arkadmin' in passdb.
[2017/09/21 00:36:03.344808,  3]
../source3/auth/auth_winbind.c:60(check_winbind_security)
check_winbind_security: Not using winbind, requested domain
[ARK-CENTOS-SMB4] was for this SAM. [2017/09/21 00:36:03.344835,  2]
../source3/auth/auth.c:315(auth_check_ntlm_password)
check_ntlm_password:  Authentication for user [arkadmin] -> [arkadmin]
FAILED with error NT_STATUS_NO_SUCH_USER [2017/09/21 00:36:03.344858,
2] ../auth/gensec/spnego.c:768(gensec_spnego_server_negTokenTarg)
SPNEGO login failed: NT_STATUS_NO_SUCH_USER [2017/09/21
00:36:03.344879,  4] ../source3/smbd/sec_ctx.c:217(push_sec_ctx)
push_sec_ctx(0, 0) : sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 1 [2017/09/21
00:36:03.344891,  4] ../source3/smbd/uid.c:491(push_conn_ctx)
push_conn_ctx(0) : conn_ctx_stack_ndx = 0 [2017/09/21 00:36:03.344901,
4] ../source3/smbd/sec_ctx.c:321(set_sec_ctx_internal)   setting sec
ctx (0, 0) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 1 [2017/09/21 00:36:03.344919,  4]
../source3/smbd/sec_ctx.c:439(pop_sec_ctx)   pop_sec_ctx (0, 0) -
sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 0 [2017/09/21 00:36:03.344949,  3]
../source3/smbd/smb2_server.c:3097(smbd_smb2_request_error_ex)
smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: idx[1]
status[NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE] || at
../source3/smbd/smb2_sesssetup.c:134 [2017/09/21 00:36:03.345308,  4]
../source3/smbd/sec_ctx.c:321(set_sec_ctx_internal)   setting sec ctx
(0, 0) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 0 [2017/09/21 00:36:03.345337,  4]
../source3/smbd/sec_ctx.c:321(set_sec_ctx_internal)   setting sec ctx
(0, 0) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 0 [2017/09/21 00:36:03.345351,  4]
../source3/smbd/sec_ctx.c:321(set_sec_ctx_internal)   setting sec ctx
(0, 0) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 0 [2017/09/21 00:36:03.345365,  4]
../source3/smbd/sec_ctx.c:321(set_sec_ctx_internal)   setting sec ctx
(0, 0) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 0 [2017/09/21 00:36:03.345535,  3]
../source3/smbd/server_exit.c:246(exit_server_common)   Server exit
(NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_RESET)
```

here is my smb.conf content

```
#working since 2017-8-1 with sssd?+ad
[global]
netbios name = ARK-CENTOS-SMB4
security = ADS
#workgroup = QA
workgroup = QA.ARKIVIO.COM
kerberos method = secrets and keytab
realm = QA.ARKIVIO.COM
log file = /var/log/samba/%m.log
log level = 4
#password server = *
#passdb backend  = tdbsam
#template shell  = /bin/bash
#template homedir = /home/%u
#winbind separator = +
local master    = no
domain master   = no
#auth methods    = guest sam_ignoredomain winbind
#guest ok        = no
server string = Samba Server Version %v
max log size = 5000
load printers = No
#idmap config * : backend = tdb
#preferred master = no
wins support = no
wins proxy = no
dns proxy = yes
#name resolve order = wins bcast host lmhosts
name resolve order = host lmhosts wins bcast

# Winbind idmap RID settings
#    winbind use default domain = yes
#    allow trusted domains = yes
#    winbind enum users = yes
#    winbind enum groups = yes
#    winbind nested groups = yes
#    idmap config QA : backend = rid
#    idmap config QA : default = yes
#    idmap config QA : range = 100-33554431
#    idmap config * : range = 33554432-67108862
#    idmap config * : backend = tdb
#    printing        = bsd
#    load printers   = no
#    disable spoolss = yes
#    printcap name   = /dev/null
#    log level       = 10
#    log file        = /var/log/samba/samba.log.%m
#    max log size    = 5000
#    debug timestamp = yes
#    oplocks         = 1
#    unix extensions = yes
#    clustering      = 0
#    smb ports       = 445, 139
#    mangled names   = yes
#    default case    = lower
#    case sensitive  = auto
#    preserve case   = yes
#    short preserve case = yes
#    bind interfaces only = yes
#    interfaces = lo bond0:2 eth0:1 eth0:2 eth2 eth3
#    dos filetimes = 1
#    create mask = 777
#    admin users = administrator

[arkc1]
comment = centos samba4 share1
path = /rocket/cifs/cifs1
#public = no
#read only = no
writable = yes
#guest ok = yes
#inherit permissions = 1
#inherit acls = 1
#map acl inherit = 1
#vfs objects = acl_xattr
#acl_xattr:ignore system acls = 1

#valid users = @"autostoradmins@qa.arkivio.com"
#valid users = administrator,auto-stor,arkadmin,Domain Admins,autostoradmins
valid users = administrator@qa.arkivio.com,auto-stor@qa.arkivio.com,arkadmin@qa.arkivio.com,@"Domain Admins@qa.arkivio.com",@"AutostorAdmins@qa.arkivio.com","QA.ARKIVIO.COM\AutostorAdmins",arkadmin@QA.ARKIVIO.COM
#admin users = administrator,auto-stor,arkadmin,Domain Admins,autostoradmins,QA\arkadmin,QA.ARKIVIO.COM\arkadmin
admin users = administrator@qa.arkivio.com,auto-stor@qa.arkivio.com,arkadmin@qa.arkivio.com,@"Domain Admins@qa.arkivio.com",@"AutostorAdmins@qa.arkivio.com",arkadmin@QA.ARKIVIO.COM,QA\arkadmin,QA.ARKIVIO.COM\arkadmin

[arkc2]
comment = centos samba4 share2
path = /rocket/cifs/cifs2
#public = no
#read only = no
writable = yes
#guest ok = no
#vfs objects = acl_xattr
#acl_xattr:ignore system acls = yes

admin users = administrator@qa.arkivio.com,auto-stor@qa.arkivio.com,arkadmin@qa.arkivio.com,@"Domain Admins@qa.arkivio.com",@"AutostorAdmins@qa.arkivio.com",arkadmin@QA.ARKIVIO.COM,QA\arkadmin,QA.ARKIVIO.COM\arkadmin
valid users = administrator@qa.arkivio.com,auto-stor@qa.arkivio.com,arkadmin@qa.arkivio.com,@"Domain Admins@qa.arkivio.com",@"AutostorAdmins@qa.arkivio.com","QA.ARKIVIO.COM\AutostorAdmins",arkadmin@QA.ARKIVIO.COM,QA\arkadmin,QA.ARKIVIO.COM\arkadmin

[root@ark-centos-smb4 /]# getent passwd arkadmin@qa.arkivio.com
arkadmin@qa.arkivio.com:*:1712439520:1712400513:arkadmin:/home/arkadmin@qa.arkivio.com:/bin/bash
[root@ark-centos-smb4 /]# id arkadmin@qa.arkivio.com
uid=1712439520(arkadmin@qa.arkivio.com) gid=1712400513(domain users@qa.arkivio.com) groups=1712400513(domain users@qa.arkivio.com),10(wheel),1712439592(autostoradmins@qa.arkivio.com),1712439438(certsvc_dcom_access@qa.arkivio.com)
```

domain users already recognized by centos,see following results

```
getent passwd arkadmin@qa.arkivio.com
arkadmin@qa.arkivio.com:*:1712439520:1712400513:arkadmin:/home/arkadmin@qa.arkivio.com:/bin/bash

getent passwd QA\\arkadmin
arkadmin@qa.arkivio.com:*:1712439520:1712400513:arkadmin:/home/arkadmin@qa.arkivio.com:/bin/bash
```

please give some advice,thanks

Comment: The important part of all the log file dump is `check_ntlm_password:  Authentication for user [arkadmin] -> [arkadmin]
FAILED with error NT_STATUS_NO_SUCH_USER [2017/09/21 00:36:03.344858,`. Is `arkadmin` the account you're using on the Windows system? How is your CentOS system able to authenticate that name - `sssd` perhaps? You haven't told us.

Comment: yes arkadmin is the domain user that could login to the centos server,it was recognized by getent,id, will append command results to the question

Comment: also per centos7.4 release notes,samba has issues with sssd authentication,should wait for new samba package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After updating sssd* packages to 1.15.2-50.el7_4.6,restart smb service,i could access samba AD shares,it caused by sssd authentication broken with AD

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve a similar issue by adding the following lines to my smb.conf under the `[global]` section:

```
[global]
idmap config * : backend = tdb
idmap config * : range   = 1000-9999
```

source: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/338723

Comment: thanks,but still get access denied error after applying those configuration items